# Map Offset, Design not in Line with Map when I load my workspace

Tags: qgis, offset

We are facing an issue when using QGIS to plan and design FTTx networks. We create the design and it all looks great and print it via composer to be validated on site but when we go back into the design to make changes the map is offset by a few millimeters which means we have to redo the entire design to fit the map again....

How can I fix this so we don't have to redo all this work?

We are using map CRS - EPSG: 3857

Comment: You mean the map element moves from its original place in Print Composer?

Comment: No in the main Qgis window, print composer works just fine, sorry I'm not sure why my tags were edited to show print composer...??

Comment: Please clarify what ends up misaligned with what. Are you printing something and then bringing it back into QGIS? If not, what exactly is your workflow?

Answer (score 0):

In the main QGIS workspace you can use bookmarks to rememeber the spatial extent, scale and coordinate system of your area of interest.

Press `Ctrl+Shift+B`to show the bookmarks panel and start creating them using the *Add Bookmark* button.

[image]

Comment: That is great thank you, however, we have 19 projects so 19 designs already done which all have a problem with the map offset, using the bookmark is great when starting a new project but its not helping with the map and design alignment....Do you perhaps know how we can re-align the map or design to fit each other again?